# Apache+Home Server not allowing External Traffic

Tags: apache-http-server, windows-7, webserver, web-hosting

Not sure what the ruling is on asking new questions but I felt like my previous question was answered   [in this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/253643/apachehome-server-and-no-page-loading?tab=active#tab-top).

So now I have my server correctly allowing me to setup directories outside of my wamp/www folder, and it is allowing me access to the sites via my url www.acyrid.com, only within my network.  Those were the two of the big points of the previous question. It also has still has access to localhost via the wamp/www directory which was the third major point of that post.

My problem now is: **Why am I not able to receive any form of external traffic**?

I have had a few friends test the above url ([www.acyrid.com](http://www.acyrid.com)) and they simply time out after a bit, I have also tested it via a proxy and and also time out.

Below I will paste my httpd and httpd-vhosts conf files for you guys to see if you can possibly help me find the error but a bit more information first.

I do have winows firewall disabled by using command *netsh advfirewall set AllProfiles state off*
My OS is windows 7 Home Premium 64bit
I have opened up port 80 on my router and set it to TCP on ip 192.168.1.50 (the "static" ip I've chosen)
My router is the

I have the following:

- Server (Windows 7)
- Apache 2.2.17
- MySQL 5.1.53
- PHP 5.3.4.
- Linksys E2000 Router
- Windows 7 Home Premium (64bit)

I have done the following:

- Disabled Windows Firewall via command
  prompt: *netsh advfirewall set
  AllProfiles state off*
- Opened Ports 80 (Http) & 21 (FTP) to TCP on IP: *192.168.1.50* ("Static" IP)
- External IP has been forwarded correctly via freedns.afraid.org (*I know this because the game server I am running is allowing external connections via acyrid.com:25565*)

**HTTPD.CONF**

```
    #
    # This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
    # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
    # See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2> for detailed information.
    # In particular, see 
    # <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html>
    # for a discussion of each configuration directive.
    #
    # Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
    # what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
    # consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
    #
    # Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
    # of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
    # server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
    # with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/foo.log"
    # with ServerRoot set to "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2" will be interpreted by the
    # server as "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/foo.log".
    #
    # NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
    # instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
    # If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which Apache.exe is located
    # will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
    # an explicit drive letter in absolute paths to avoid confusion.

    #
    # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
    # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
    #
    # Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
    # ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
    # at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
    # httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
    #
    ServerRoot "C:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.2.17"

    #
    # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
    # ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
    # directive.
    #
    # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
    # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
    #
    #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
    Listen *:80

    #
    # Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
    #
    # To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
    # have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
    # directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
    # Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
    # to be loaded here.
    #
    # Example:
    # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
    #
    LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
    LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
    LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
    LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
    #LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
    #LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
    #LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
    #LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
    LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
    LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
    #LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
    #LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
    LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
    LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
    LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
    #LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
    LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
    LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
    #LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
    #LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
    LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
    #LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
    #LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
    #LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
    #LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
    #LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
    #LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
    LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
    #LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
    #LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
    LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
    #LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
    #LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
    #LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
    #LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
    #LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
    #LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
    #LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
    LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
    #LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
    LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
    #LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
    #LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
    LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
    #LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
    #LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
    LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
    #LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
    LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
    #LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    #LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
    #LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
    #LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
    #LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
    LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
    #LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
    #LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
    #LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
    #LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
    #LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
    #LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
    #LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
    #LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
    LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
    LoadModule php5_module "C:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.4/php5apache2_2.dll"

    <IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
    <IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
    #
    # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
    # httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
    #
    # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
    # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
    # running httpd, as with most system services.
    #
    User daemon
    Group daemon

    </IfModule>
    </IfModule>

    # 'Main' server configuration
    #
    # The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
    # server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
    # <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
    # any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
    #
    # All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
    # in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
    # virtual host being defined.
    #

    #
    # ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
    # e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
    # as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
    #
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost

    #
    # ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
    # This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
    # it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
    #
    # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
    #
    ServerName localhost:80

    #
    # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
    # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
    # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
    #
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/"

    #
    # Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
    # to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
    # directory (and its subdirectories). 
    #
    # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
    # features.  
    #
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
    </Directory>

    #
    # Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
    # particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
    # you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
    # below.
    #

    #
    # This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
    #
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/">
        #
        # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
        # or any combination of:
        #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
        #
        # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
        # doesn't give it to you.
        #
        # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
        # for more information.
        #
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

        #
        # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
        AllowOverride all

        #
        # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
        #

    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1

    </Directory>

    #
    # DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
    # is requested.
    #
    <IfModule dir_module>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
    # viewed by Web clients. 
    #
    <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
        Satisfy All
    </FilesMatch>

    #
    # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
    # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
    # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
    # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
    #
    ErrorLog "C:/wamp/logs/apache_error.log"

    #
    # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    #
    LogLevel warn

    <IfModule log_config_module>
        #
        # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
        # a CustomLog directive (see below).
        #
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

        <IfModule logio_module>
          # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
          LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
        </IfModule>

        #
        # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
        # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
        # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
        # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
        # logged therein and *not* in this file.
        #
        CustomLog "C:/wamp/logs/access.log" common

        #
        # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
        # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
        #
        #CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule alias_module>
        #
        # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
        # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
        # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
        # Example:
        # Redirect permanent /foo http://localhost/bar

        #
        # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
        # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
        # Example:
        # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
        #
        # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
        # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
        # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
        # the filesystem path.

        #
        # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
        # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
        # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
        # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
        # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
        # directives as to Alias.
        #
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "cgi-bin/"

    </IfModule>

    <IfModule cgid_module>
        #
        # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
        # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
        #
        #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
    </IfModule>

    #
    # "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
    # CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
    #
    <Directory "cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    #
    # DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
    # if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
    # If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
    # a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
    # or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
    # keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
    # text.
    #
    DefaultType text/plain

    <IfModule mime_module>
        #
        # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
        # filename extension to MIME-type.
        #
        TypesConfig conf/mime.types

        #
        # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
        # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
        #
        #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
        #
        # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
        # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
        #
        #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
        #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
        #
        # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
        # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
        #
        AddType application/x-compress .Z
        AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php3

        #
        # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
        # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
        # or added with the Action directive (see below)
        #
        # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
        # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi

        # For type maps (negotiated resources):
        #AddHandler type-map var

        #
        # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
        #
        # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
        # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
        #
        #AddType text/html .shtml
        #AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    #MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

    #
    # Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
    # 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
    #
    # Some examples:
    #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
    #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
    #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
    #ErrorDocument 402 http://localhost/subscription_info.html
    #

    #
    # EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
    # memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
    # files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
    # be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
    # filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
    # broken on your system.
    #
    #EnableMMAP off
    #EnableSendfile off

    # Supplemental configuration
    #
    # The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
    # included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
    # the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
    # necessary.

    # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf

    # Multi-language error messages
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf

    # Fancy directory listings
    Include conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf

    # Language settings
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf

    # User home directories
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf

    # Real-time info on requests and configuration
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-info.conf

    # Virtual hosts
    Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

    # Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-manual.conf

    # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf

    # Various default settings
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf

    # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
    #Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
    #
    # Note: The following must must be present to support
    #       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
    #       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
    #
    <IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    </IfModule>

    Include "C:/wamp/alias/*"
```

**HTTPD-VHOSTS.CONF**

```
    #
    # Virtual Hosts
    #
    # If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
    # machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
    # use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
    # IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
    #
    # Please see the documentation at 
    # <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
    # for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
    #
    # You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
    # configuration.
    #
    # Use name-based virtual hosting.
    #
    NameVirtualHost *:80
    #
    # VirtualHost example:
    # Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
    # The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
    # match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
    #
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      DocumentRoot C:/wamp/www/acyrid
      ServerName www.acyrid.com
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all 
    </Directory>
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/acyrid">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all   
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Thank you in advance for any answers, and if I did break any rules or precedents about posting new questions I apologize.  I did read through the FAQ before posting a new question and I am attempting to be as thorough as possible.

**UPDATE:**

So the fixes I was provided do allow me to access the link www.acyrid.com and see the site but only from my network no one else can access it yet. Any ideas on that one guys?

Comment: Do you have your router configured to forward all traffic coming in on port 80 and 21 from the outside to the IP address of your server on the inside?

Comment: Yes I have gone into my router (Linksys E2000) and to the Port forwarding section to open up ports 80 and 21 on the "Static IP" 192.168.1.50 via the router.

Comment: I have gone to further extent today trying to solve this problem by taking the following steps:  1) Set a rule in Windows 7 Firewall (which is disabled via the command in the above post) to allow TCP traffic on port 80 through the firewall. 2) I also went into my router and set it to not filter anonymous internet requests in it's firewall settings.  I'm doing everything I can think of and still can get no External visibility on the site.

Comment: Active Connections_____________________________________________________________________
  
Proto__Local Address___________Foreign Address__State_______PID  
TCP____0.0.0.0:80______________0.0.0.0:0________LISTENING___4320__________________________________  This shows to be the service ID for wampache listening on all ip's to port 80, unless I am mistaken.  So this should be listening for outside connections.

Comment: So I'm a bit of a bonehead, Suddenlink of course blocks incoming traffic on port 80 should have known better.  Thank you to everyone for your help. ***Resolved***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I noticed right away:

- `Listen localhost:80` means that Apache will only answer requests from the localhost and the site(s) won't be available on the Internet. Typically this line is just `Listen :80` which will listen on all host IP addresses or you can enter the specific external IP address of the host.
- You only want one `NameVirtualHost` line and it should match the `Listen` entry. See [Common Misconfigurations](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/CommonMisconfigurations) for a few good examples and explanations.
- Similarly, you want your `VirtualHost` entries to match your `NameVirtualHost` line.
- You have two entries for www.acyrid.com. Either delete one or combine them as needed. The DocumentRoot for the second entry is most likely wrong.

Some specific suggestions on fixing it and troubleshooting:

- Start with the simplest possible configuration, test it to confirm it works, and then begin adding to it, testing each step along the way. I would start by just having one VirtualHost entry and testing it on localhost until it works. I would then test it externally and confirm it works. Only then would I move onto more complex or additional VirtualHost entries.
- Make sure your server is externally accessible from the Internet. For a simple test just try pinging, ftp, telnet, ssh to your server. If you cannot reach your server then the issue is a network/DNS configuration issue. Solve that before you try solving your Apache issues.
- Pay close attention to the type of errors you get when trying to connect to your site. These will help narrow down the cause of the issue. For example, a 403 Apache error is usually due to misconfigured file/directory permissions (Apache is trying to serve file a but can't read it). Playing with VirtualHosts entry trying to fix a 403 error will likely just end up getting you a more broken site.

Answer (score 0):

**In httpd.conf:**

```
Listen *:80
```

Replace `Listen localhost:80`

**In httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

The above line, only once at the top of the file.

Change every instance of:

```
<VirtualHost ... >
```

to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

For more information:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/bind.html

Answer (score 0):

So the fixes I was provided do allow me to access the link www.acyrid.com and see the site but only from my network no one else can access it yet.  Any ideas on that one guys

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to log into your router and "port forward" port 80 WAN to port 80 LAN of the system Apache is running on.

Then you'll also need to modify the native Windows Firewall to allow all incoming port 80 requests (unblock the port and have no ip restrictions).

Note that your ISP could be blocking incoming port 80 requests. If they do, call in and tell them to unblock that port. It sometimes will require a higher-level support tech or manager to get them to understand what you are talking about.

Edit:
Your www.acyrid.com website works for me... I see you are using a "frame forwards" for port 8080.

Comment: You can open Windows firewall using: netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Open Port 80" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=80